# What's the function of the word 'than'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions

> More families consist of one-parent households or two working parents; consequently, children are likely to have less supervision at home **than** was common in the traditional family structure.

What's the function of the word 'than'?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary, and find that 'than' is a conjunction used to introduce the second element in a comparison?

Comment: People often talk about ***than-clauses***, which are a subset of ***comparative clauses***. So I'd say ***than*** is just a "function word" used to introduce (some) comparative clauses. I think that at least *sometimes* (perhaps only in informal contexts) it can be discarded on the grounds that the relationship of the following clause to preceding text is obvious anyway.

Comment: Thinking a bit more, I can't actually come up with any context where the comparative conjunction ***than*** can be completely discarded. But in ***Mine's bigger'n 'is*** the word ***than*** might be reduced to just /n/ (no additional schwa or enunciated /r/ necessarily being present, but initial /h/ discarded from ***his***).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *... children are likely to have less supervision at home* [*than was*
> *common in the traditional family structure*].

"Than" has a comparative meaning where the comparison here is between the amount of supervision that children have at home today with that of the traditional family.

Grammatically, the function of "than" is **head**:

"Than" is a preposition, so the whole of the bracketed expression is a preposition phrase with "than" as head. The sequence of words that immediately follows "than" is a comparative clause functioning as complement of "than".

"Than" has a comparative meaning: the comparison is between the amount of supervision of children at home today with that of the traditional family.